# Finding records based off distinct values in one table and different values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following tabes (bold is PK, Italic is FK)

inventors(**inventorid**, inventorfirst, inventorlast, *patentno*)

assignees(**assigneeID**, AssigneeName, AssigneeCity, AssigneeState *patentno*)

InventorID and Assignee ID are just Autonumbered identities for index purposes and are otherwise meaningless.

What I am trying to find is instances where someone with the same first and last name, but have at least 2 different assignees

What I have so far (which I know is very minimal)

```
SELECT a.assigneename, i.inventorfirst+' '+ i.inventorlast as Name
FROM inventors i, assignees a
WHERE i.patentno=a.patentno
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a list of inventorFirst that has more than one assigneeName against their inventions then try the following:

```
;with inventor_cte(inventorfirst,cnt)
as
  (
  SELECT 
        i.inventorfirst
        , count(distinct a.assigneename) cnt
  FROM 
       inventors i 
       inner join  assignees a ON 
            i.patentno=a.patentno
  GROUP BY i.inventorfirst
  )
select inventorfirst from inventor_cte where cnt>1
```

An alternative to the above is to use the `HAVING` clause:

```
 SELECT i.inventorfirst
  FROM 
       inventors i 
       inner join  assignees a ON 
            i.patentno=a.patentno
  GROUP BY i.inventorfirst
  HAVING count(distinct a.assigneename) > 1
```

I prefer the first syntax - unsure which is more efficient.

Comment: This gives me the following error:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'inventor.InventorFirst' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: my code is via sql-server; not too sure about mySql. I've edited the solution so it now has the correct grouping and will work in sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Here , i used left outer join for different assignees .
If inventors does not have any assignees then 'isnull' function put blank value.
Please , use below sql query :

```
SELECT 
      isnull(a.assigneename,'') as assigneename
      , i.inventorfirst+' '+ i.inventorlast as Name
FROM 
     inventors i 
     left outer join  assignees a on 
          i.patentno=a.patentno
```

Comment: The query works, but what I want specifically is for the results to only display the names of inventors who have patents with more than one assignee